# How to understand the text 'You don't mean it, do you? No, I do'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the movie "The Devil Wears Prada", there is a dialog:

---

> Nate: ...And then we can stop pretending like we have anything in common anymore.

> Andy: You don't mean it, do you?

> Nate: **No, I do**

> Andy: Maybe this trip is coming at a good time...

---

I'm so confused about the answer by Nate, "No, I do".
I think it should be "Yes, I do", means that I do mean that we should stop pretending....

Comment: People say it both ways, they mean the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, English does not have a word like *si* in French and *doch* in German, whose availability reduces the temptation to use *no* in this way.

Comment: Although the question cited as a duplicate of this one **could** be answered in a way that would answer this question as well, neither of the formal answers submitted to that earlier question focuses on the core "No, it does" vs. "Yes, it does" question. In fact, both seem far more taken with the duplicate occurrence of the "no" in the dialogue "No! No! I am!" The most valuable observations relevant to this poster's question appear in two comments beneath the poster's question there—and as we are constantly reminded, comments could disappear at any time. Hence my vote to reopen this question.

Comment: Just "yes" or "no" are ambiguous. There are lots of other questions on answering negative questions. [How to answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity), [This on agreeing with both "yeah" and "no"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419994/answering-negative-questions-with-yeah), [Ambiguity of no](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552511/what-does-this-answer-to-a-negative-question-mean), etc. [Search!](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=answering+negative+question)